# Integral calculation in R

Tags: r, math, functional-programming

```
z <- function(x)(sin(3*x)*(1-cos(3*x))
integrate(z, lower = 0, upper = 2pi)
```

I'm trying to calculate this integral in R.Τhe result should be 0 but the program gives other result.I'm a beginner and i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: `2pi` should be `2 * pi`, and the first line is missing a closing parenthesis. Please correct this.

Comment: you are right but it still gives me an error     ` Error: unexpected symbol in:
"z <- function(x)(sin(3*x)*(1-cos(3*x))
integrate"`

Comment: You have only applied parts of my correction, please read my comment again.

Answer (score 2):

You have some syntax issues. Correction:

```
z <- function(x)(sin(3*x)*(1-cos(3*x)))
integrate(z, lower = 0, upper = 2*pi)
```

[R FIDDLE](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=XTA3o7TZ)

Or the same without the outer parenthesis:

```
z <- function(x) sin(3*x)*(1-cos(3*x))
integrate(z, lower = 0, upper = 2*pi)
```